# How to detect a string is full-string or half string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Now,i am developing an autotest tool that using japannese, because japannese word using full-string in C++ so i must write a function to detect  when a string is full-string or half-string and how to convert a string from full-string( ex: jis string) to half string but i have not experience about it.some one can help me, plz?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? And by "full string" do you mean "full width characters"?

Comment: yes, full string means that full-width characters and half-string means that half-width characters. In english usually use half-string ( use 1 byte to store string) but in japanese use full-string.           Example: 'name' is string that use half-string and '名前' is string use full-string

Comment: Do you mean japanese use UTF-16?

Comment: in japannese they use Shif-JIS

Comment: The encoding used is entirely separate to whether the characters are half-width or full-width Japanese characters, as I understand it...

Comment: Shift-JIS encodes Unicode codepoints using 8bit octets. C# strings, `std::wstring`, etc use UTF-16, which encodes Unicode codepoints using 16bit words. You do not deal with Shift-JIS inside your app. You read Shift-JIS data from an outside source (file, socket, etc), and write Shift-JIS data to an outside destination. Internally, read encoded data and convert to UTF-16 (`MultiByteToWideChar()`, `System.Text.Encoding.GetString()`, etc), and then convert back only when saving (`WideCharToMultiByte()`, `System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes()`, etc). Process data using UTF-16 (or even UTF-32) as needed.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding).

Comment: With respect to my previous comment, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#Half-width_kana - zenkaku vs hankaku for Katakana.